# Prove that $K_m \mathop{\square} K_n$ contains an Eulerian circuit

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

Prove that $K_m \mathop{\square} K_n$ contains an Eulerian circuit if and only if $mn\equiv 0,1\pmod 4 $ and both $m,n \gt 1$. anyone know to find the hint or some reference ?

Note : $K_m \mathop{\square} K_n$ it means Cartesian product of two graphs.

Answer (score 1):

**Corrected.**

You’re using a different symbol for it, but I’m assuming that you mean the Cartesian graph product as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs).

HINT: We can take the vertex set of the product graph to be $[m]\times[n]$; $\langle i,j\rangle$ is adjacent to $\langle k,\ell\rangle$ iff either

- $i=k$, and $j$ is adjacent to $\ell$, or
- $j=\ell$, and $i$ is adjacent to $k$.

Since two vertices of a complete graph are adjacent iff they are not equal, we see that $\langle i,j\rangle$ is adjacent to $\langle k,\ell\rangle$ in the product graph iff either $i=k$ and $j\ne\ell$, or $j=\ell$ and $i\ne k$. In particular, the degree of any vertex of the product graph is $(m-1)+(n-1)=m+n-2$.

- Observe that $m+n-2$ is even iff $m$ and $n$ have the same parity.

This is **not** equivalent to the statement that $mn\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$ and $m,n>1$: the case $K_3 \mathop{\square} K_4$ is a counterexample, since $3\cdot4=12\equiv 0\pmod 4$, but every vertex of the graph has degree $5$, so the graph has no Euler circuit. Unless some other notion of Cartesian graph product is intended, the second condition should be that $m\equiv n\pmod 2$ with $m,n>1$.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693969/how-is-this-possible-to-convert-a-long-string-to-a-number-with-less-characters

Comment: @Kermani: I only just came online and saw this; **Drupalist**’s suggestion of using Huffman encoding looks good to me.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I understand the concept for cartesian graph product, i am stack to prove $mn\equiv 0,1\pmod 4 $ and both $m,n \gt 1$. Could you like to tell me, how to format cartesian product symbol in here ? I try to find in here [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference], but i didn't find it

Comment: @Angelo: (Sorry to be so late getting back to you.) You can get the box symbol ($\square$) used in Wikipedia with `\square`, but to get the right spacing here you want `K_m \mathop{\square} K_n`, producing $K_m \mathop{\square} K_n$. However, I just realized that I must have been half asleep when I wrote my answer, because the theorem is false. If $m=3$ and $n=4$, then $mn\equiv 0\pmod 4$, but each vertex of $K_3 \mathop{\square} K_4$ has degree $5$, so the graph has no Euler circuit. Either the problem is dealing with some other graph product, or it was stated incorrectly, and the correct ...

Comment: ... statement is that the graph has an Euler circuit iff $m\equiv n\pmod 2$ and $m,n>1$. By the way, Cartesian products of complete graphs are also known as [*rook graphs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook's_graph).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you for your explanation, it is very clear now

Comment: @Angelo: You’re welcome; I’m glad that it helped.